# javascript return both radio button values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following, which shows upcoming matches and allow users to vote who will win

[image]

Team names and fixtures are dynamically pulled from db, it is unlikely that number of matches will be the same for each round, thus nr matches vary for each round.

When user made his selection before he clicks submit, I would like to display something like:

You have selected:

**Force** (Selected) To Win Crusaders(not selected)

**Highlanders** (Selected) To Win Cheetahs(not selected)

:

I got this working correctly like so:

[image]

But Im stuggling to put the "*VS" part team not selected* in the string. I.E it is easy enough to put the selected teams value in the string but im struggling to get the name from team not selected.

Perhaps this fiddle will give you a better idea to what im trying to achieve:

https://jsfiddle.net/timcoetzee/L9gna8a0/3/

```
function handleClick() {
    // Get all the inputs.
    var inputs = makePicks.elements;
    var radios = [];

    //Loop and find only the Radios
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; ++i) {
        if (inputs[i].type == 'radio') {
            radios.push(inputs[i]);
        }
    }

    myradiovalue = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if (radios[i].checked) {
            if (myradiovalue == "") myradiovalue = radios[i].value
            else myradiovalue = myradiovalue + ", " + radios[i].value
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("dispPicks").innerHTML = "YOU HAVE SELECTED " + myradiovalue;
    return false;
}

<form name="makePicks">
    <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" id="x" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks1" value="Chiefs"><span>Chiefs</span>

    </label>
    <label class="yellow">
        <input type="radio" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks1" value="Hurricanes"><span>'Hurricanes'</span>

    </label>
    <label class="pink">
        <input type="radio" name="picks1" value="draw" onclick="handleClick()"><span>Draw</span>

    </label>
    <br />
    <label class="green">
        <input type="radio" id="x" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks2" value="Lions"><span>Lions</span>

    </label>
    <label class="yellow">
        <input type="radio" onclick="handleClick()" name="picks2" value="Stormers"><span>'Stormers'</span>

    </label>
    <label class="pink">
        <input type="radio" name="picks2" value="draw" onclick="handleClick()"><span>Draw</span>

    </label>
    <br />
</form>
<div id="dispPicks"></div>
```

Any help or advise very much appreciated

Comment: If I understand correctly, are you trying to display 'not selected' checkbox values along with the 'selected' ones?

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh both selected and not selected value

Comment: `Array.prototype.forEach(document.querySelectorAll("type['radio']"), function(radio) {
        radio.onclick = function() {
            document.getElementById("dispPicks").textContent = "YOU HAVE SELECTED " + this.value;
        }
    });` This is an easier way to select and assign events to a group of elements. It's not an answer, so I'm just throwing it here.

Comment: @SterlingArcher that some impressive Javascript, which I could code like that, learning....

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/gbh8g11y/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function ff() {
    var msg = "you have selected:<br/>" ;
    var radios = makePicks.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio]');
    for(var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) {
        if(radios[i].checked) {
            msg += getMessage(radios[i].getAttribute('name')) + "<br/>";
        }
    }
    document.getElementById("dispPicks").innerHTML = msg;
}

function getMessage(nm) {
    var rds = makePicks.querySelectorAll('input[type=radio][name=' + nm + ']');
    var checked = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < rds.length; i++) {
        if(rds[i].checked)
            checked = i;
    }
    if(checked == 2)
        return rds[0].value + " (not selected) to draw " + rds[1].value + " (not selected)";
    else if(checked == 1)
        return "<b>" + rds[1].value + "</b> (selected) to win " + rds[0].value + " (not selected)";
    else
        return "<b>" + rds[0].value + "</b> (selected) to win " + rds[1].value + " (not selected)";
}
```

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/L9gna8a0/8/)